# spring -integration TCP gateway, connect and receive data from Socket

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to implement TCP Client in Spring integration. I have a remote TCP server, who pumps in the data on to a socket. My Spring based TCP client has to receive the data from that socket as it comes in.

As a Client I am not sending any data from my side to the server, just connect and receive data. Looking at this http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/94696-want-to-configure-simple-tcp-client-to-receive-data-from-java-based-tcp-server?view=thread, I understood this is not possible. But, the answers received are pretty old, now is there any configuration available?

Please  let me know if you have further questions.

@updated with configuration

```
<bean id="javaSerializer" class="org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer" />
<bean id="javaDeserializer" class="org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer" />

<context:property-placeholder />

<!-- Client side -->

<int:gateway id="gw"
    service-interface="com.my.client.SimpleGateway"
    default-request-channel="input" default-reply-channel="replies" />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
    type="client" host="localhost" port="5678"
    single-use="false" so-timeout="10000" serializer="javaSerializer"
    deserializer="javaDeserializer" so-keep-alive="true"/>

<int:channel id="input" />

<int:channel id="replies">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<!-- <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway" request-channel="input" 
    reply-channel="reply" connection-factory="client" request-timeout="10000" 
    reply-timeout="10000" /> -->

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter
    id="outboundClient" channel="input" connection-factory="client" />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter
    id="inboundClient" channel="replies" connection-factory="client"
    client-mode="true" retry-interval="10000" auto-startup="true" />
```

Here is my remote TCP Client:

```
    final GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    context.load("classpath:config.xml");

    context.registerShutdownHook();
    context.refresh();

    final SimpleGateway gateway = context.getBean(SimpleGateway.class);
    int i=0;
    while(i++<10){
    String h = gateway.receive();
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+h);
```

My TCP Mock Server:

```
while(true) {
     try {
        System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
        serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");

        Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Just connected to "
              + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());

        DataOutputStream out =
             new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        out.write("ACK\r\n".getBytes());

        out.flush();

       //server.close();

     } catch(SocketTimeoutException s) {
        System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
        break;
     } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;
     } 
  }
```

My Gateway class:

```
public interface SimpleGateway {    
    public String receive();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` (`<ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter/>`) is normally run in server mode - it listens on a socket for incoming connections to client.

However a `clientMode` (`client-mode`) boolean was added for precisely this use case. It will connect to a server and receive incoming data from it. If the connection is lost, it will retry connecting (on a configuration schedule).

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-adapters):

> Normally, inbound adapters use a type="server" connection factory, which listens for incoming connection requests. In some cases, it is desirable to establish the connection in reverse, whereby the inbound adapter connects to an external server and then waits for inbound messages on that connection.
>
> This topology is supported by using `client-mode="true"` on the inbound adapter. In this case, the connection factory must be of type `client` and must have `single-use` set to false.
>
> Two additional attributes are used to support this mechanism: `retry-interval` specifies (in milliseconds) how often the framework will attempt to reconnect after a connection failure. `scheduler` is used to supply a TaskScheduler used to schedule the connection attempts, and to test that the connection is still active.

If a scheduler is not provided, the default `taskScheduler` bean is used.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I am following your example for this on GIT. I will do above said configurations, and will come back with results. Hopefully I will get it ! :)

Comment: I tried with the explained configurations. But I see no response from the server. I am not sure if I have missed any thing or may be incorrect. I have an interface gateway defined with method as: `public String receive(String text);`. It just receives data from the TCP server. The xml configurations are as described above in the documentation. Please find above the configuration. In My Client `TCPClient`, I call `receive()`, but I receive no data.

Comment: After updating the configuration above, I tried using custom desializer, rather java deserialilzer. The good news is, I see the data coming into `deserialize()` method, but not to my `TCPClient.receive()`. It is getting stuck at `org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection
` in run method, as okToRun is true. I am writing this in detail because, I see, you are the author of this class.

Comment: I am confused; your configuration is inconsistent with your question. `As a Client I am not sending any data from my side to the server, just connect and receive data.` Your client is indeed sending data.

Comment: Earlier I was trying to just connect and receive data, which was not working. So I thought, let me try with sending some data and receive response back. Now I am able to get response, I see data coming in my `deserialize()` method. This is not propagated to its caller.This is the problem phase now.

Comment: Your description implies the deserializer is waiting for more data. Since you are using `\r\n`, remove the serializer/deserializer from the configuration so the default is used. When sending data, from the client, you don't need to add `\r\n` - `"ping"` - the default serializer will add those. If you send `ping\r\n` the server will get two messages (the second one empty).

Comment: Got it! I tried again back with connect and receive logic with some code changes. I am getting the response back from server and on client side I get this. Okay, as per your previous comment, 2 messages are sent to server. Thank you Gary!

Comment: One follow up question on this. Why does my client close connection as soon as he gets response from server? Is there a way to keep my client alive? Yeah, I used `so-keep-alive ` in client factory, but not working.

Comment: The client does not close the connection. I suggest you start another question with an example of what you are seeing.